# Avada Theme - Display results from a specific category

Tags: pages, templates, page-template

In the Avada Theme there is a page template called 'FAQ page', this 'FAQ Page' can have categories (faq_category_1) and in these categories there can be unlimited questions with answers.

This part of the code (below) gets the categories uncluding the questions/answers, all of them.

What I want to achieve is I only want to show the questions/answers from one specific category that is for example equal to the page title ($title) by using an if statement.

```
    <?php $portfolio_category = get_terms('faq_category_1');
    if($portfolio_category):
    ?>
    <ul class="faq-tabs clearfix">
        <li class="active"><a data-filter="*" href="#"><?php echo __('Alle', 'Avada'); ?></a></li>
        <?php foreach($portfolio_category as $portfolio_cat): ?>
        <li><a data-filter=".<?php echo urldecode($portfolio_cat->slug); ?>" href="#"><?php echo $portfolio_cat->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
        <div class="accordian fusion-accordian">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordian-one">
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'avada_faq_1',
                    'nopaging' => true
                );
                $gallery = new WP_Query($args);
                $count = 0;
                while($gallery->have_posts()): $gallery->the_post();
                $count++;
                ?>
                <?php
                $item_classes = '';
                $item_cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'faq_category_1');
                if($item_cats):
                foreach($item_cats as $item_cat) {
                    $item_classes .= urldecode($item_cat->slug) . ' ';
                }
                endif;
                ?>
```

I am a beginning coder (also my first question here:)) and I am not sure where I exaclty need to adjust the code. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, reading the specific reason I must say I agree, I did not think it through. It is not a specific Wordpress question. I will keep this in mind in the future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to keep in mind. In WordPress you have *taxonomies* and *terms*. For instance *Category* is a **taxonomy**, and let's say *Portfolio* is a **term** belonging to the "Category" taxonomy.

What the code you just posted does is to take **all the terms** of the "faq_category_1" taxonomy and print all those values as a menu at the top. Then it makes another query to get **all the posts** of the post type "avada_faq_1" and uses javascript to filter them by term.

If you want to display only the questions of a specific term, you can modify that query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'avada_faq_1',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy', // Could be "faq_category_1" or a custom taxonomy
            'terms' => $title,
            'field' => 'slug'
        )
     )
);
```

You can only select terms by either ID or slug, so $title should be converted to slug before making the query, you can do this by using `sanitize_title`.

Remember that after you change the query the javascript filtering would be pretty much pointless, so you should remove the terms menu at the top.